# How to refresh inline JQuery ui datepicker using angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have created a directive for datpicker, which is as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('datepicker', ['myService', '$q', function (myService, $q){
    return{
         restrict: 'A',
         require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
              var selectedDropDownVal = attrs.selectedValue;
              var events = null;
              var eventPromise = myService.getCalendarEvents(selectedDropDownValue);
              return eventPromise.the(function(result){
                    *some logic*
                    return events;
              });

              return $q.all([eventsPromise]).then(function(){
                     return element.datepicker({
                           minDate:today,
                           dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                           beforeShowDay: function (date){
                                *some logic to highlight dates*
                           },
                           onSelect: function (date){
                                scope.$apply(function(){
                                     ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                                });
                           }
                     });
              }

         }
    };
});
```

This works as I would like it to.

---

So the problem I am having is when the dropdownlist item changes I would like to refresh this datepicker so it would now go back to server with new dropdown value and return highlighted events.

---

What have i tried so far?

I have created a ng-change="UpdateDatepickerSelectedValue()" which is as follows:

```
$scope.UpdateDatepickerSelectedValue = function () {
        console.log("value has changed!");

        console.log("attempting to refresh datepicker!");

        var eventDatepicker = angular.element(document).find('#eventCalendar');
        console.log(eventDatepicker);
        eventDatepicker.datepicker('refresh');
    };
```

However this doesn't refresh the datepicker!

Can someone please advise? also is this a correct approach? are there any alternatives?

Thanks.

Kush

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix for this issue:

The issue was that when a drop down value changes i needed the datepicker to update with new highlighted dates.

The way I achieved this was to introduce a $watch on the element attribute.

So my code now looks like:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('datepicker', ['myService', '$q', function (myService, $q){
    return{
         restrict: 'A',
         require: 'ngModel',
         scope: {
              selectedValue: '@'
         }
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl){

              var events = null;

              var getEvents = function(value){
                  var eventPromise = myService.getCalendarEvents(value);
                  return eventPromise.then(function(result){
                        *some logic*
                        return events;
                  });
              }

              scope.$watch('selectedValue', function(value){

                 var response = getEvents(value);

                 return $q.all([eventsPromise]).then(function(){
                     return element.datepicker({
                           minDate:today,
                           dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                           beforeShowDay: function (date){
                                *some logic to highlight dates*
                           },
                           onSelect: function (date){
                                scope.$apply(function(){
                                     ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                                });
                           }
                     });
                });
              }

         }
    };
});
```

Hopefully this helps others too! :)